# Importing .obj files and rig info file with script

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, obj

I have .obj files(mesh) and corresponding rig info .txt files.
rig info files have information of joint, root, skinning, and hierarchy of joint.
I want to import mesh and rig info to a Armature and export that to .fbx file
How can I do that?

I'm trying to use RigNet(https://github.com/zhan-xu/RigNet), AI that generates rig info from obj file. This project using Maya to combining result, but I don't have a maya license. (Trial license has expired), so I want to do that on blender.
I am reading blender python API, but it is quite difficult.

rig info file format example

```
joints root 0.00000000 0.39418566 0.09227327
joints root_dup_0 0.00271110 0.39689678 0.09498437
joints root_dup_1 0.00197620 0.39616185 0.09424946
...
joints joint_22 0.11304832 0.64783418 -0.03318732
joints joint_18 0.29738784 0.41645390 0.07064430
root root
skin 0 joint_11_dup_0 0.2714 joint_11_dup_2 0.2522 joint_7 0.3040 joint_21 0.1724 
skin 1 joint_11_dup_0 0.2714 joint_11_dup_2 0.2522 joint_7 0.3040 joint_21 0.1724 
...
skin 3913 joint_11_dup_0 0.2714 joint_11_dup_2 0.2522 joint_7 0.3040 joint_21 0.1724 
skin 3914 joint_11_dup_0 0.2714 joint_11_dup_2 0.2522 joint_7 0.3040 joint_21 0.1724 
hier root root_dup_0
hier root root_dup_1
...
hier joint_21 joint_22
hier joint_20 joint_18
```

Thank you for reading and answering.

Comment: This sounds like it’s not so much about combining two files together, as it is about importing a .rig file into blender. Is that correct?

Comment: @TheLabCat Yes, That's more proper expression. I edit question. Thanks!